# Object Properties in .js files not properly executing in HTML

Tags: javascript

I'm very new to JavaScript (I have very limited Python experience as well) and am trying to find a simple way to call an object property from another .js file I have feeding into my HTML base file.

Snip of flowers.js

```
const rose = {name:'Rose', color:'Red', pic:'Rose.png'};
```

Snip of HTML base file

```
<html>
<head> 
<script src="flowers.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<img id='flowerOne' src=rose.pic style='width:100px'>
</body>
</html>
```

This works fine if I paste the image reference in directly ("Rose.png" within img src) but not if I write out rose.pic, which theoretically has the exact same reference? I've managed to get .js file functions to work just fine, it just seems to be calling object properties where I'm struggling.

I'm probably not understanding something - any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the source of the image in javascript.
Just use this

flowers.js

```
 const rose = {name:'Rose', color:'Red', pic:'Rose.png'};
 document.getElementById('flowerOne').src = rose.pic
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head> 
</head>
<body>
<img id="flowerOne" style='width:100px'>
<script src="flowers.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try moving the script tag to the end of the body section -in the head section the image element hasn't been parsed or created yet.

Comment: Appreciate your help! Unfortunately this still seems to be not working for me. The image does not load on startup as expected. I have some buttons that do a similar thing with getElementById and the images load properly with the flower images I choose. It might be a problem specifically with the .js file code, because if I paste that directly into the HTML between script tags it does not work either.

Comment: Could you check your console and tell me if you have any errors? You may have the path wrong and that is why it will not render.

Comment: You know what, I figured out I was being a bit of a dunderhead. I was writing "getElementByID" instead of "getElementById". All is good now. I think the answer here was very helpful in providing context to the situation though. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use JavaScript to update the `src` attribute of the html img. You can accomplish that by first selecting the image as follows:

```
let img = document.querySelector('img');
```

Then you can assign it a new `src` attribute value as follows:

```
img.src = rose.pic;
```

The image can have an empty `src` attribute, a placeholder image, or no `src` attribute at all. Your choice.

[Learn more about the `querySelector` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Comment: `let img = document.querySelector(''#flowereOne'')` would narrow down the image returned to a specific image element.